# donet build error MSB4019 on execute command to sonaqube

Tags: .net, msbuild

When I'am execute this command to build my solution to sonarqube, the follow error apears

"C:/Program Files/sonarqube/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /key:"iob.br.iobauditoreletronicosped" /d:sonar.host.url="http://10.100.108.7:9000" /d:sonar.token="sqp_67a2a3cbc392766ac1097dd730567ec3ab03d12f"
dotnet build "C:\Users\juliano.maciel\source\repos\iob.br.iobauditoreletronicosped\src\CeltralInformacoes.Web.NV\CeltralInformacoes.Web.NV.csproj" -c Release

C:\Users\juliano.maciel\source\repos\iob.br.iobauditoreletronicosped\src\CeltralInformacoes.Web.NV\CeltralInformacoes.Web.NV.csproj(2733,3): error MSB4019: o projeto importado "C:\Program Files\dotnet
\sdk\7.0.307\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" não foi localizado. Confirme se a expressão na declaração Import "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.307\Micros
oft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" está correta e se o arquivo existe no disco.

In Visual Studio installer dont see any section to builder tools to download
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJzjb.png)

Donwload build tools correctely

Comment: [MSB4019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb4019?view=vs-2022) - `MSB4019: The imported project 'name' was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration 'declaration' is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

Comment: The path looks wrong. I would expect the path to be `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`. It seems to be looking in the sdk folder for `Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`. I don't know how that would happen.

Comment: I'am solved this problem, in the get started of sonarqube is indicating to use dotnet build command but this project is a .NET Framework project, in this case the right command is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022 \Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Users\juliano.maciel\source\repos\iob.br.iobauditoreletronicosped\src\Mitrius.sln" /t:Rebuild

Comment: That makes sense. The `dotnet` tool has no knowledge of .NET Framework (because it is not cross-platform) and doesn't know how to locate .NET Framework files and components. The `dotnet` tool has an embedded copy of `msbuild`. `dotnet build` is equivalent to `msbuild /t:build` (except the non-embedded msbuild supports both .NET and .NET Framework when running on Windows).